Connecting to device in the Lab via LAN cable
Good Day, First time poster, long time lurker.
I am a PhD student working in the Lab and by no means a programming expert, so this question might be very simple.
I had an electron gun connected to a router in our Lab and used a homemade python code to read it out and it worked:
    host = 'Old IP address'
    port = 2005
    addr = (host,port)
    buf = 1024
    
    def Connect(self, verbose=1):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.s.settimeout(0.5)

    def ReadName(self, verbose=1):
        self.s.sendto(b'Info',self.addr)
        # time.sleep(0.5)
        module, inaddr = self.s.recvfrom(self.buf)
        print(module)

Yesterday we connected the electron gun directly to the computer and changed the IP address. I can still control it via the web interface, so I know the IP address I am using is correct. However, the code does no longer work and I get a timeout error.
This would be the updated code, nothing in the Connect or Read name was changed.
    host = 'New IP address'
    port = 2005
    addr = (host,port)
    buf = 1024

The manual for the electron gun specifies that port 2005 should be used, but is that still the case if I now connect it directly to the PC? Sorry if that is a super trivial question, but I am really at my wits end. Because the first code block worked well, I don't suspect that the buffer is the problem.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks

This doesn’t have a lot to do with programming, it is more probably a configuration issue. When connecting a device to a PC directly, you have more things to set up, like DHCP, PPPoE, Static address, mask and gateway, etc.

@Cyril Thanks for the answer. The device was set up by our IT wizard, so I suspect he has configured all of this to work. I use the socket package, which was used in my previous Lab. However, I found nothing in the documentation that would indicate any difference between connecting the cable directly to the PC or via a router
